# google app engine request log breakdown

Tags: google-app-engine

Here is an example line from one of python appengine apps in the admin console Logs section filtered to 'Request Only':

```
01-22 07:19PM 55.483 /zone/5 200 82ms 161cpu_ms 115api_cpu_ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; W...
```

Is there an explanation somewhere of what the columns are?

Here's what I'm curious about:

Column 3: 55.483 - I assume this is seconds in the datetime, but it is strange to be after the 'PM'

Column 6: At first I thought it was the time to serve the response - but here 82ms is less than 161cpu_ms and 115api_cpu_ms, so what is this time?

Column 9: 0kb - I assume this is the size of the response.  Our response is less than 1kb for this request, so I assume they are rounding down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column 6: is the time to serve the response. The reason CPU time is greater is because many operations are parallelized. What are you doing in this request? The CPU is the total CPU being used to generate the request.

Column 9: It's probably less rounding down and more integer truncation.