# app engine requests logs show all static file sizes zero byte?

Tags: google-app-engine

I need to analyze app engine logs to know the bandwidth used. All requests show 0b for static files. How to change this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I asked a related question once, [google app engine request log breakdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121984/google-app-engine-request-log-breakdown) and it seems they either round down or truncate for less than 1k when you use the admin site.

However, if you export the logs using appcfg.py request_logs you should be able to get a finer grained value for bandwidth used, at least it works for me with python.  Note, the %b does not include request headers, so you will still see some 0's.    http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Downloading_Logs

`appcfg.py request_logs . logname.txt`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I resolved this issue by serving files with python script. Now all logs contain file size.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are saying you are serving your static files through python instead of static in app.yaml.  This might not be a good idea because you are going to use extra cpu and possibly bandwidth.  I encourage you to set this back after you get the numbers you are looking for.